# how to make the main route of a website end in .ec .com .es in Angular

Tags: angular

I am practicing in angular and I would like to know how to make a webpage such as https://www.mercadolibre.com, When you enter, it asks for your country and then it sends you to the route https://www.mercadolibre.com.exampleContry

Comment: As H0-pe pointed out below, this is nothing you can actually do in Angular. These are two different web applications, one running at https://www.mercadolibre.com, which contains a list of links to different applications, each of them running under their respective domain

Answer (score 2):

You could try `window.location.href = 'https://www.mercadolibre.com.exampleCountry'` wherever you want the redirect to happen.

Keep in mind that this is an entirely new domain.

You might consider implementing something that redirects to an internal route like `https://www.mercadolibre.com/exampleCountry`. Not really sure what your use-case is.